# Восстановить окно после сворачивания, WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, winapi

Пытаюсь сделать нечто вроде гаджетов на рабочий стол (винда 10)
Использую WPF
Мне нужно окно,

1. поверх рабочего стола, но ниже всех остальных окон
2. его невозможно свернуть

Первая проблема решена с помощью

```
PInvoke.User32.SetWindowPos(MainWindowHandle, (IntPtr)1, 0, 0, ScreenW, ScreenH, 0);
```

Как решить вторую? А именно, при использовании функции "показать рабочий стол" (Win + D) восстановить окно обратно

Мои попытки:

-> Повесить `WindowState = WindowState.Normal;` на `OnWindowStateChanged` - не работает, Win + D сворачивает окно, но статус остается Normal
-> Сделать окно дочерним к окну рабочего стола `Program Manager` - кажется не работает, изменений не видно
-> `SetWindowPos(...)` не работает
-> `User32.SetForegroundWindow(...)` не работает
-> `PInvoke.User32.ShowWindow(MainWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE);` не работает
-> Код

```
PInvoke.User32.SetWindowPos(MainWindowHandle, (IntPtr)(-1), 0, 0, ScreenW, ScreenH, 0); // mosttop
Thread.Sleep(10);
PInvoke.User32.SetWindowPos(MainWindowHandle, (IntPtr)1, 0, 0, ScreenW, ScreenH, 0); // bottommost
```

Работает но выглядит  как адский костыль

Чё делать?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте копать в этом направлении

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd, StringBuilder ss, int count);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new();

    private void MainWindow_OnStateChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
        {
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var ct = _cts.Token;
            ForceRestore(ct);
        }
        else
            _cts.Cancel();
    }

    private async void ForceRestore(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        try
        {
            using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct))
            {
                cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
                while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100, cts.Token);
                    if (IsAllMinimized())
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(100, cts.Token);
                        ShowWindow((int)process.MainWindowHandle, 1);
                        SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
    }

    private bool IsAllMinimized()
    {
        var handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out var processId);
        var proccess = Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(processId));
        if (proccess.ProcessName != "explorer")
            return false;

        const int nChar = 256;
        var t = GetWindowText(handle, new StringBuilder(nChar), nChar);
        return t == 0;
    }
```

И чем больше в системе открыто окон, тем больше нужна задержка. Если вызвать эти методы пока идет процесс сворачивания всех окон, то станет `WindowState = WindowState.Normal`, но визуально не появится. Нужно вызывать после того, как все окна в системе свернулись.

Вместо паузы можно попробовать смотреть на foreground процесс и титл - при свернутом это будет explorer с пустым титлом

**upd:** Обновил до этого варианта. Все равно не 100%. Пришлось навесить Delay и после детекта проводника, а то окно могло появиться и тут же исчезнуть

**upd2:** В принципе можно не таймаутами надеяться на авось, а добавить проверку, что окно стало foreground и пинать его пока не станет.

Comment: Спасибо. Есть ли способы рисовать на рабочем столе кроме создания окна?

Comment: @Ciyox я таких не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже что я нашел решение, нужно сделать окно дочерним, но не к `Progman`, а к `SHELLDLL_DefView`